Counterexample for non-convexity of $x/y$
Given the function $f(x_1,x_2) = x_1 / x_2$ for $x_1, x_2 > 0$. The Hessian of $f$ has a negative eigenvalue such that $f$ is non-convex.
However, I'm struggling to find an example of points $x = [x_1,x_2]$ and $y = [y_1, y_2]$ with $t \in [0,1]$ which violates the convexity definition, i.e.,
$$
f( t*x + (1-t) y) \leq t f(x) + (1-t) f(y)
$$
Can you please help me find an example?
I tried to look at different lines, which turned out to be all convex:

$f(x_1,x_2)$ is convex in $x_2$
$f(x_1,x_2)$ is linear in $x_1$
$f(x,x) = 1$ is constant in $x$
$f(1-x,x) = $ is convex in $x$


A straight-forward calculation shows that for this function,
$$
 f\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}, \frac{y_1+y_2}{2}\right) > \frac 12 \bigl( f(x_1, y_1) + f(x_2, y_2)\bigr)
$$
holds if and only if $(y_1-y_2)(x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1)$ is positive. A concrete example is
$$
 f(4, 2) = 2 > \frac 53 = \frac 12 \bigl( f(7, 3) + f(1, 1)\bigr) \, .
$$

$t=\frac 1 2, x_1=1, x_2=4, y_1=3,y_2=8$ would do.  $f(t[x_1,x_2]+(1-t)[y_1,y_2]) =\frac 2 6=\frac 1  3$ and $tf([x_1,x_2])+(10t) f([y_1,y_2])=\frac 5 {16}$ Of course, $\frac1 3 > \frac 5 {16}$
